# Why all my usb devices keep connecting and disconnecting?

Tags: usb, connection

I'm on Linux Mint 19.2,and anything that i connect on my usb ports,either is my android phone or usb flash drive,keeps disconnecting immediately after i connect it.
Why is this happening?

EDIT: Sorry,i've noticed now that only the android phone and the usb flash drive it disconnects from any port because i moved the keyboard in another port and it doesn't disconnect.

Comment: Test these devices on another computer. If they work correctly, USB on your computer may have a problem.

Comment: A few months ago i tested them on my laptop and had no problem.I also think it's a problem with my usb ports,but why the keyboard and mouse works and the other ones don't?

Comment: I can't really say. Perhaps because they use less electricity. A repairman will know more.

Comment: Ok.Thank you so much

Comment: BTW, I've noticed some hubs can be flaky. Also,sometimes it's a loose connector, sometimes a break in a cable as it flexes... and sometimes, something else.

Comment: I believe that the USB ports are damaged somehow because it's an old desktop,at least i tried...idk..

Comment: I've managed to dual boot W10 and Linux Mint and on windows it doesn't do this thing with connecting and reconnecting.Could be a problem with linux kernel?What should i do?Should i try another linux distro?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved by replacing the PSU(power supply unit).The old power supply that was connected to the motherboard had too many pins and i think it was giving too much power to it.Hope it helps someone.